# Retrieve email IDs from the Azure AD group using

Tags: c#, azure

I have AD groups created and is in Azure. Examples of the Azure AD group name is something like this Azure_ABC_XYZ_DEV, Azure_ABC_XYZ_Test etc... There are multiple different members with in each of the groups. I need to retrieve those member's email IDs and then need to send email based on certain conditions. I cannot use Azure AD connector available in logic apps to retrieve group members due to some company reasons. To send email I will be using SMTP connector(Which is fine). So, I will  have to use Azure function/Microsoft graph using C# to fetch those email IDs. Can some one please guide me how to do this. May be step by step approach for the code. Thanks in Advance! Help is much appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SkOU.png)

Comment: How come you can't send an email to the group's own address and let Azure expand it out and deliver the message for you?

Comment: These groups are not email enabled. Also, these groups needs to be provided access to certain shared folder as well. Hence we do not want to change this to email enabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) of a group. There is a `mail` property that is what you want.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var members = await graphClient.Groups["{id}"].Members
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Then you could [Send mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-1) to the email addresses you get from the previous step.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    },
    CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    }
};

var saveToSentItems = false;

await graphClient.Me
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Allen, Thank you for quick response but I am not able to initiate authProvider given GraphServiceClient( authProvider). The method AuthorizationProvider is not available when I try to set  AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

Comment: @user1789330 Did you add the SDK? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation